In an ideal situation, why should no friction exist when an object rolls?
As per my textbook, “a body like a ring or sphere rolling without slipping over a horizontal plane will suffer no friction in principle. At every instant, there is just one point of contact between the body and the plane, and this has no motion relative to the plane“
I could not understand how the point has no relative motion with respect to the plane… as the object moves, the point of contact will also move on the plane. So there should be relative  motion between the point and the plane.

These are simplifying assumptions to make problems easier to solve. There is another assumption in here, already, which we rarely mention: that bodies are incompressible, i.e. they are not changing shape under mechanical stress.

The contact point doesn't slide along the surface - it is simply lifted above it and is replaced by the next point. However, the (static) friction is present - it prevents the point from slipping and thus effectively makes the wheel rotate.

So how come you don't account for static friction in the f=ma calculation?

yes, this answer is incorrect

@EmilSriram Most of what we do at this level of classical mechanics are ad-hoc idealizations. We assume that there is enough friction to prevent the rolling object from slipping, but then we are ignoring the energy loss due to that friction anyway. From a fundamental point of view classical mechanics with geometric objects is not a self-consistent physical theory. That's perfectly fine. We are not trying to construct a perfect theory with these examples but we are trying to build simple systems that are easy for students to analyze.

@EmilSriram I didn't say that.

@PatoGalmarini be more specific. Just saying incorrect doesn't make it so - we are physicists, not philosophers.

@Roger V. In an idealized state, of course, how does a wheel spin at constant velocity if there is friction then?

if a ball is rolling with the right velocity, it does not experience friction and it keeps its angular momentum, and it can keep rolling forever without slowing down. Of course, we are talking about an ideal rigid ball that only makes contact at a point, we are physicists, not engineers.

I mean, if there was friction then the CM would slow down, unless there is a second force that compensates for it, which one?

@PatoGalmarini there's no friction between the wheel and the axis. The friction at the contact point is a static one, it performs no work.

for a system of particles with internal forces, such as a wheel, it is true that $F_{external.total}=Ma_{CM}$, which for our wheel reduces to  $F_{friction}=Ma_{CM}=0$, unless you claim that $a_{CM}$ is not zero.

@PatoGalmarini the question does not specify whether the wheel is rolling with constant velocity or not. Also, friction is not the only force - the cm acceleration is determined by the net force, not by the friction alone.

well, he is assuming that there is no friction, and you contradicted him, as if this was not possible. I agree that in the presence of other forces you can have static fiction, and in such case static friction does no work in a reference frame where the floor is at rest.

@PatoGalmarini that's the nuance: they are not assuming no friction. They say that a body [...] will suffer no friction in principle - if the body rolls without acceleration (which is not specified) and other forces acting on it, it will "suffer no friction", but because the friction force is zero, not because the friction coefficient is assumed to be zero. IMHO the statement in the textbook is deficient. Anyhow, the Q. is not really about this, but about the stationary of the contact point - this whole discussion in the comments is tangential to what the Q. actually asks.

The "point of contact" is a mathematical concept. It does not have any mass, so it is not, strictly speaking, a physical object.
Two other things relevant that you didn't ask but are relevant for understanding.
A wheel does have friction, on the axis.
Ans rolling body will deform even so slightly, but the deformation requires work and draws energy, converting it to heat. For that reason, a high pressure in the tires of your car or bike is better than a low pressure.

Not sure why this got a downvote. It correctly points out that the point of contact is an abstract idealization and that real rolling objects deform.

Imagine a small car sitting on flat pavement. The car is in neutral, and the wheels are straight. The goal is to push the car as far as possible in one minute time.
You would likely choose to push the car in the direction that lets the wheels roll. It would be much more difficult to push the car sideways. Why?
If you push sideways, you are initially dealing with the static friction of the car and attempting to slide the points of contact between the wheels and the pavement (kinetic friction). You push the car an inch, and the $\it{same}$ points of contact are moved an inch.
If you push so that the wheels can rotate, there are still 4 points of contact, but when you push the car an inch, these points are at different locations on the wheels than when you started. By pushing on the car you've caused the wheels to pivot about these points. Because the ground is flat, you have to keep pushing for the wheels to keep pivoting. If the ground were an inclined plane, the wheels would continue pivoting on their own (due to gravity), with the points of contact being translated to different locations down the plane, but to the points of contact, they are not sliding with respect to either the wheels or the pavement, and therefore there is no friction other than static friction.

Consider the frame where the wheel is not translating (i.e. the one that is traveling at the same speed as the wheel).
The bottom of the wheel moves at velocity  $v = -R \omega $.
To go back into the laboratory frame (where the wheel is moving again), first note that when a wheel is rolling without slipping, its translational velocity is $v = R \omega $. If this is not obvious, keep in mind that when the wheel rotates $2\pi$, the wheel travels a distance equal to its circumference, or $d = 2\pi R$. Therefore, $d = R \theta $, and differentiating gives $v = R\omega$. Now going back to the laboratory frame, each point on the wheel has an added velocity $v_T $ so $ v = v_{cm} + v_T$ and for the point at the bottom of the wheel, $ v = -R \omega + R \omega = 0 $, hence it is at rest ( of course until the pivot point switches instantaneously). Static friction will only act if there is a force trying to cause relative motion between the two surfaces, which there isn't in this case. 

"Static friction will only act if there is a force trying to cause relative motion between the two surfaces, which there isn't in this case." Isn't there a force trying to move the point of contact away from the surface?
